# How to create multiple sub-folders in cookiecutter template using a sub-folder template

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I want to create a template for our internal projects.

The layout of the project contains a variable amount of sub-folders.

I would like to specify the sub-folders to create, inside some configuration file.
For example, I have the following folder structure:

```
my_project
|
|___ Tables
|  |
|  |__ Table1    <--- The folders I would like to create
|  |__ Table2    <---|
|  |__ Table3    <---|
|
|___ Other_folders
```

The configuration file should have something like this:

```
{
  "prj_name": "my_project",
  "tables": ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"]
}
```

I  have tried to create the following structure:

```
{{cookiecutter.prj_name}}
|
|___ Tables
|  |
|  |__ {% for table in cookiecutter.tables %}{{table}}{% endfor %}
|
|___ Other_folders
```

and added to `cookiecutter.json` the mentioned configuration.

I ran cookiecutter using `--no-input`. And the result was only a single sub-folder (Table1).

Also tried to use the following folder name: `{% for table in cookiecutter.tables.keys() %}{{table}}{% endfor %}`
With the following configuration:

```
{
  "prj_name": "my_project",
  "tables": {
    "table1": "table1",
    "table2": "table2",
    "table3": "table3"
  }
}
```

The output was still a single sub-folder (Table2Table1Table3)

Any idea how I can achieve the desired structure?

Answer (score 5):

Well eventually I wrote a python script that uses [Cookiecutter's package functions](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/cookiecutter.html) with two template folders.

One template folder for the main project, and one template folder for the tables folders.

And the script would use `cookiecutter.main.cookiecutter` function to create the main project, and the sub folders in a loop.

I've wrote a more detailed post in a blog.
Not sure about the rules here about posting links to personal blogs. So if someone in the future would like to see it, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi I am interested to see your extension. I am looking for this feature as well. Could you post your solution? :)

Comment: @maryhadalittlelamb Thanks for the interest. The post is here: https://igorbasko01.github.io/cookiecutter/python/2020/02/04/cookiecutter-sub-folders.html
You can skip down to the solution at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I went with a low-tech solution here. My use case was pretty simple and there's a finite amount of folders I needed to create so my solution is manageable to me. YMMV, but I thought I'd offer it here in case it works for someone else.

I basically prepopulated the number of directories I figure I would ever need. I just used Python's `format` in a `range` loop to prepopulate however many folders I needed.

```
cookiecutter/mycookiecutter/
├── cookiecutter.json
└── {{cookiecutter.project_name}}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 0\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][0]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 1\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][1]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 10\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][10]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 11\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][11]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 12\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][12]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 13\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][13]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 14\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][14]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 15\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][15]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 16\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][16]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 17\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][17]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 18\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][18]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 19\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][19]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 2\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][2]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 3\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][3]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 4\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][4]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 5\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][5]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 6\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][6]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 7\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][7]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    ├── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 8\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][8]}}{%\ endif\ %}
    └── {%\ if\ cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"]|length\ >\ 9\ %}{{cookiecutter.account_info["accounts"][9]}}{%\ endif\ %}
```

cookiecutter.json

```
{
    "project_name": "test",
    "account_info": {
        "accounts": [
            "root",
            "corp",
            "dns",
            "dev",
            "prod"
        ]
    }
}
```